# Synonyms for 'non-court' venues

Tags: mediation

There may be a need to take an HOA to court for breach of contract.  Before filing in small claims court, it makes sense to search the governing document for any requirements to resolve the matter in [non-court venues](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/mediation).  What are the synonyms for non-court venues.  I Googled mediation and found these synonyms:

```
arbitration
conciliation
intervention
negotiation
reconciliation
intercession
interposition
```

Any additions to the list (please edit this post) are appreciated.

Are there any 'obvious' (to a seasoned professional) synonyms that have been missed?

Comment: "alternative dispute resolution", often abbreviated ADR, is another synonym.

Answer (score 1):

Except *arbitration*, many of the terms you list are essentially synonymous to *mediation*.

Doubting that (and without knowing whether) this is any different in Florida, I can say that in Michigan the Small Claims court orders the parties to attend mediation, and the court schedules one accordingly. Mediation is a prerequisite before small claims court even schedules a court hearing. A party loses the case if he or she does not attend mediation.

Whenever possible (in this or other matters), avoid arbitration and any clauses that require it --or list it-- for dispute resolution. Wrong rulings from arbitration are very hard to reverse even if the law and the evidence clearly support the party who should have prevailed.

Comment: I understand that FL small claims will automatically refer the case to [mediation](https://adr.findlaw.com/mediation/mediation-vs-arbitration-vs-litigation-whats-the-difference.html) for nonbonding discussion, at the risk of arrogance: given my perceived strength of the case I have a hard time imagining conceding anything in mediation.  I would prefer to summary judgement if that were available.

Comment: @gatorback Courts supposedly report that mediation significantly reduces their caseload. But that does not mean that you "have" to compromise at mediation. And, although mediation may seem an unnecessary hassle and its format is different than a court hearing, it can still give you a little bit of exposure in presenting your legal arguments (as well as knowing your opponent's) for subsequent litigation.

Comment: Agreed.  My hope is that they have an Ace-card in the back pocket.  My bias (stubbornness) won't allow me to compromise unless I am negotiating from a position of recovering all funds and negotiating a penalty for an egregious violation of contract law (no idea if there is such a statue).

Comment: @gatorback Sanctions under *contract law* are typically limited to losses arising from the breach (plus maybe court costs and attorney fees if in civil court), not punitive. Some statutes provide for treble damages under specific scenarios, but I honestly doubt that this case would prompt a court to award any sort of punitive damages even if the court finds that the Association clearly and flagrantly did the wrong thing.

Comment: These terms are similar but are non synonyms, for example, "negotiation" does not involve a neutral third-party and "conciliation" has a neutral-third party who actively formulates solutions which a "mediation" does not.

Comment: @DaleM Thanks. Those distinctions are educative (and I see that Wikipedia [cites another one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conciliation)), but the key point is that judgment and arbitration essentially differ from everything else in that these two are an imposition to at least one party, whereas negotiation, conciliation, mediation, etc. entail the parties' [voluntary] acceptance of a *settlement*.

Comment: @IñakiViggers See how [voluntary] a court ordered mediation is

Comment: @DaleM "*See how [voluntary] a court ordered mediation is*" It is not, but [my comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31749/synonyms-for-non-court-venues/31753?noredirect=1#comment58082_31753) clearly states that mediation would entail "*the parties' [voluntary] acceptance of a settlement*" (brackets in original). Unless all parties willfully accept the proposed outcome, then that tentative settlement would not be binding. Ordering the parties to engage in mediation is different than imposing on them an outcome proposed therein.